# How do I define an exported constant?

Tags: c++, constants, c++20, c++-modules

I've been trying the new modules feature, but I'm unable to export a global constant. The exporting seems to compile fine, but when importing the compiler complains that the constant is not declared. My code:

test.cpp

```
export module test;

export struct my_type { int x, y; };
export constexpr int my_constant = 42;
export int my_function() { return my_constant; }
```

main.cpp

```
import test;

int main() {
    my_type t{1, 2};
    int i = my_function();
    int j = my_constant; // <- error here
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm using g++ 11.1.0 on linux: `g++-11 -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts test.cpp main.cpp -o main`

The error message is: `error: ‘my_constant’ was not declared in this scope`

Comment: Can you try exporting it just as `const`?    I wonder if modules and `constexpr` don't get very well along yet.

Comment: @rturrado except `const`doesn't work either.

Comment: Both `const` and `constexpr` define internal linkage (i.e. `static`) if not otherwise specified. I can't find anywhere if `export` affects this, so you probably need something like `export extern const int my_constant = 42;`

Comment: @olm This seems to do the trick. Post it as an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

const-qualified variables have internal linkage by default, so it might be necessary to write it as

```
export extern const int my_constant = 42;
```

According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration the `export` definition should make the variable have external linkage, so you might have hit one of the corners where C++20 is not yet fully implemented.

Comment: "you might have hit one of the corners where C++20 is not yet fully implemented" I did a quick search and didn't see a defect filed against g++ for this. Should there be one?

Comment: Doesn't `export` give external linkage just by itself? I thought it would override the internal linkage from `const`.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `inline`

```
export inline constexpr int my_constant = 42;
```

Comment: Outside of the very special case of `extern "C++"`, inline variables aren’t ever needed in a module (since they can’t be defined in multiple translation units).